# The admonition icons are not rendered in generated pdf

Tags: pdf, asciidoc

I'm using ASCIIDOC for the first time , the problem is that after generating the pdf file, the admonition icons are no more rendered.

PS: it's rendered in the html file.

Here's an example:

```
 IMPORTANT: Tout fichier utlisé doit être  ajouté dans le Makefile sinon le compilateur ne le voit pas lors de la compilation.
```

THis is the command i used :

```
a2x -f pdf --fop myfile.xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a2x` calls `dblatex`, you have to set the path for the icons as a dblatex-option, f.ex:

```
a2x -f pdf --icons --dblatex-opts='-V -T db2latex -I /etc/asciidoc/images/icons' test.txt
```

(When you use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) instead of `dblatex` you can set the icons path as described in the book ["DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide"](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintIcons.html).)

Comment: When you use `fop` the dblatex-opts doesn't apply.